# special java HTTP POST request

Tags: java, http, post, httprequest, ddos

I have read quite a lot of questions here, but allready can`t find some help.

My problem is a "DDOS-Protection".

I try to connect to http://www.leya2.eu
But with every "method" i try, i will not get trough this blazing-fast "site".

```
public class Login {

public static void main(String[] args) {
try{
    URL url = new URL("http://leya2.eu/?s=home");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();;
    //now all things out of my request made by "hand"
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "rcksid=kGf7FNy41w3X5jyXceoDTmosb9CgjJmGqAHgbGxWZewlwyjnUt7ias18WooEN9i3; BLAZINGFAST-WEB-PROTECT=296ba3c72e2d9a9d3854cdf776e54455; woh=morvltlevb477ruts8kgdgvkj6");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host","leya2.eu");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Referer","http://leya2.eu/?s=user");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36  ");
    conn.connect();

    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();      
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

With my Browser and these data i can connect, but with the HTTP request, everytime just the Blazing-Fast page.

Here the .js, but i really dont know, what they do =(

[Leya2-Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X51g.jpg)

Can someone help me ?

ty

Comment: Have you checked network traffic with dev-tools on browser? Is it same request/response anyway. BlazingFast might use JavaScript to forward correct page.

Comment: ive "recorded" the whole connection with blazing and the website with the network-manager in Chrome(F12)... 

Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Okay with every request the data will change.. but on access with browser they stay the same